# API Performance Testing Cloud Services

Tags: performance-testing

Folks,
  Can someone share a site they use to stress test their Restful APIs?  I need a quick benchmark and don't have time to setup jMeter or locust.
  I dont see that http://www.webpagetest.org/ supporting POST of JSON body...  Does anyone know of an alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our load testing tool http://www.stresstimulus.com has a free edition that can test Restful APIs with up to 250 concurrent threads / users. A single test wizard will guide you in recording your API request by a proxy, running the test with steady or step load and displaying the result. The report in the free edition is limited, but may be sufficient for your quick benchmarking. To activate the free edition, in the main menu, select the free edition option.